# How do "faith alone" proponents interpret James 2:24?

Tags: faith, sola-fide, works, sola-scriptura, book-of-james

James 2:24 (KJV)

> Ye see then how that by works a man is justified, and not by faith
>   only.

How do Protestants who believe in faith alone interpret James 2:24? And if they believe in *sola scriptura* (Scripture alone) how come I couldn't find anywhere in the Bible that we are saved by faith alone? But in contrary I found in James

> **works alone and not faith alone**.

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't have a checked answer.

Comment: Since this is essentially the same question, or close enough, any answers that would be posted here could just as easily be posted there. It would be better to have all the answers in one place, rather than spread out. If you believe that your question is substantially different than the other question, edit it to highlight the differences.

Comment: @DKing, sounds good with me

Comment: Answers being checked are irrelevant to whether it's a valid duplicate or not. The green check is an optional thing which question askers can do.

Comment: Also "sola scriptura" doesn't mean "Bible alone". It means that the scriptures are the highest authority, the final and sole court of appeal. Logic and reason, pulling together distant passages to develop systems of theology is still essential.

Comment: @curiousdannii `Sola scriptura (Latin: by Scripture alone) is a Christian theological doctrine which holds that the Christian Scriptures are the sole infallible rule of faith and practice. `Where do you see logic and reason?

Comment: @Grasper The sole **infallible rule** of faith and practice. Not the sole source of knowledge or theology. Do you believe in the Trinity? Where does the Bible say that the single divine essence of God exists in three persons in those words? It's a conclusion based on hundreds of passages, but we accept it as valid despite not being stated explicitly in those words. It is the same with Protestant soteriology.

Comment: @Grasper Please don't use code formatting in answers.  I put your point in quotes to get the code formatting removed. (There are a variety of web based text readers for people with disabilities that do not parse code blocked text as text).  Please review the edit, and update/upgrade as needed.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do you know the history of Trinity? How was it decided? And what do you mean "we accept it". There are churches who don't accept it the way "we" do. So how can it be based on logic and reason if many differ?

Comment: As the questions marked as the duplicate addresses the question of how Sola Fide would address James 2:24, you may also find this question helpful which addresses your separate implied question of Bible evidence for Sola Fide: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-salvation-by-faith-alone-sola-fide The proponents of "faith alone" are very commonly "scripture alone" proponents also, and often their only reason to believe it would be because of Scripture.

Comment: This question is fundamentally different from the "duplicate."  The "duplicate" is explicitly inquiring about whether justification can be seen as a binary state in light of James 2:24.  This question is asking how *sola fide* can be reconciled with James 2:24.